# Careers 2.0 Refine search - please add offer H1B check box

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Would it be possible to add a checkbox indicated that companies offer H1B visa sponsorship to Careers 2.0, in addition to those indicating telecommute jobs and jobs offering relocation?

Comment: I think this is a very good idea. Many people have a hard time finding places that are willing to do this sponsorship.

Answer (score 4):

While I think it's great if an employer adds this kind of info in their ad, I do not think visa sponsorship should be codified into a "yes/no" checkbox.

- Everybody and their dog wants into the US on a H-1B visa. Few organizations are used to sponsoring visas and know how to handle the process - usually, they are huge businesses like Google and Microsoft. If they started marking their job offers with a "we do H1B" flag, they would likely start drawing more responses from unsuitable candidates.
- Sponsoring a work visa is a *huge* effort on the employer's side as well as the employee's. Companies are often afraid of the insight they think they have to give to the INS about their everyday business dealings. (My immigration handbook encourages applicants to tell their prospective employers it's not that bad really.) They might be inclined to rethink their position if that perfect, super-awesome dream applicant walks in - but not for a <strike>mediocre</strike> normal one. Forcing employers to state a definite "yes" or "no" would unnecessarily limit everybody's options.

Comment: Yes but it is a good way in the first place to say "We could sponsor H1B if you are a good candidate" or we simply cannot.
On Ycombinator sites - companies simply write on Jobs thread are they willing to support H1B - http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4184755 e.g: San Francisco, CA. Full time. H1B okay.

Comment: @gizmo I agree it's a good thing to provide the information in the job listing if you know you can or can not sponsor. But I wouldn't make it a check box for the reasons mentioned above