# Add a flag/check box in Careers job descriptions which clearly indicates availability of visa support

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I don't see a point in SO Careers displaying me jobs from USA while I am in UK unless there is a flag clearly indicating that the company is willing to support in processing work visa for candidates. Otherwise please don't advertise opportunities where it's not even possible for a candidate to apply.

A check box saying "Visa support provided" should be available to employers who can check it to express their interest in hiring candidates from outside their country. If it is not checked then the Job Description will indicate that "No Visa support is provided". A similar check box can be added in the job search page which candidates can tick to filter out such jobs. Further, jobs which don't have "Visa support provided" checked MUST not be displayed as opportunities to people living outside the advertised country of the job.

This request is similar to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140511/careers-2-0-refine-search-please-add-offer-h1b-check-box) but requests a more generic feature available to any country.